# Deep copy in Scala using Macros vs. Reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, macros, scala-macros

I've recently implemented deep copy and deep equals using Reflection. Now I am thinking about implementing these functionalities using Macros.

Is that possible? (If I have access to the source code of the classes on which I want to use these functionalities.)

If yes, what are the advantages and disadvantages using Macros vs Reflection for these tasks?

My feeling is that using Macros would be better for two reasons:

1) more comipile time type safety

2) faster execution at runtime

Comment: [Scala Pickling](https://github.com/scala/pickling) may be of interest to you...

Comment: This seems to be a talk that is confirming my feelings : http://vimeo.com/74553075

Comment: I think that pickling claims good performance and good type safety as a result of using macros in a similar application.